# Angular 2 beta.17: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

I just upgraded from Angular 2 **beta16** to **beta17**, which in turn requires rxjs 5.0.0-beta.6. (Changelog here: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta17-2016-04-28)  In beta16 all was working well regarding Observable/map functionality. The following errors appeared after I upgraded and occur when typescript attempts to transpile:

> 1. Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable' (anywhere where I've used map with an observable)
> 2. c:/path/node_modules/rxjs/add/operator/map.d.ts(2,16): error TS2435: Ambient modules cannot be nested in other modules or namespaces.
> 3. c:/path/node_modules/rxjs/add/operator/map.d.ts(2,16): error TS2436: Ambient module declaration cannot specify a relative module name.

I have seen this question/answer but it does not solve the problem:  [Observable errors with Angular2 beta.12 and RxJs 5 beta.3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36271314/3532945)

My appBoot.ts looks like this (am already referencing rxjs/map):

```js
///<reference path="./../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser";
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
[stuff]
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core';
import { Title } from 'angular2/platform/browser';


//enableProdMode();
bootstrap(AppDesktopComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    Title
]);
```

Does anybody have any idea what is going haywire?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208801/property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I upgraded my gulp-typescript plugin to the latest version (2.13.0) and now it compiles without hitch.

UPDATE 1:  I was previously using gulp-typescript version 2.12.0

UPDATE 2:  If you are upgrading to the Angular 2.0.0-rc.1, you need to do the following in your appBoot.ts file:

```js
///<reference path="./../typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts"/>
import { bootstrap } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from "./path/AppComponent";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
// import 'rxjs/Rx'; this will load all features
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';



//enableProdMode();
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    Title
]);
```

The important thing being the reference to es6-shim/index.d.ts

This assumes you have installed the es6-shim typings as shown here:
[image]

More on the typings install from Angular here:  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/typescript-configuration.html#!#typings

Comment: Can you please mention the old version number that had the problem? Thanks.

Comment: @Meligy I was previously using gulp-typescript version 2.12.0

Comment: Awesome. I have [updated](http://www.gurustop.net/blog/2016/04/24/angular2-http-map-response-json-http_providers#1QJ491K) my article about the `map` error message to include a note for users with similar issues. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Meligy I had this same problem again when I upgraded to the Angular2 RC.  I updated my answer above to show how I solved it.

Comment: `import 'rxjs/Rx';`   // Loads all features

Comment: <reference path="./../typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts"/> needs to be added somewhere. I am just asking because i am getting error with Angular 2 RC1, TS 1.8.10. I am not using gulp but using TSC. I can see that index.d.ts exist at the location you mentioned. I also tried using import 'rxjs/Rx' in boot.ts

Comment: I found typo. @brando thanks for answer. World is back to normal.

Answer (score 283):

You need to import the `map` operator:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

Comment: The Angular team and the RxJS team both DO NOT recommend this approach of importing the entire RX like this. You should not do that. It is too large. The first answer above is fine, but the second one, not so much. @0x1ad2 can you update your answer to not include that massive import as a second option?

Comment: This is non-intuitive. Where is this documented as a dependency to implementing Observable in an Angular 2+ development?

Comment: Is this applicable to ionic 3.20.0? I got the same issue because ionic didn't automatically imported the map. Importing  explicitly works but I'm not sure it this is correct.

Comment: this does not fix the issue to many for me I had to use Pipe to instead of rxjs/add/operator/map I used rxjs/operators import with pipe and .pipe(map(res=>res.json()));

Comment: I got here after some Google searches in a time where we are now using Angular 7 and RXJS has gone through some changes. The new method is `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'`, but [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50850777/4869107) has more details.

Answer (score 68):

Rxjs 5.5 “ Property ‘map’ does not exist on type Observable.

The problem was related to the fact that you need to add pipe around all operators.

Change this,

```
this.myObservable().map(data => {})
```

to this

```
this.myObservable().pipe(map(data => {}))
```

And

Import map like this,

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

It will solve your issues.

Comment: This also applies to Rxjs 6. Every tutorial that I look at, they have the map function without pipe. This didn't work for me until I added pipe and imported map from 'rxjs/operators' exactly as the answer states.

Comment: Yes, it also applies to Rxjs 6 as well.

Answer (score 41):

In my case it wouldn't enough to include only map and promise:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

I solved this problem by importing several rxjs components as [official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#enable-rxjs-operators) recommends:

1) Import statements in one app/rxjs-operators.ts file:

```
// import 'rxjs/Rx'; // adds ALL RxJS statics & operators to Observable

// See node_module/rxjs/Rxjs.js
// Import just the rxjs statics and operators we need for THIS app.

// Statics
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

// Operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

2) Import rxjs-operator itself in your service:

```
// Add the RxJS Observable operators we need in this app.
import './rxjs-operators';
```

Comment: Yet again, the best answer on the question doesn't have the most votes. This is the best answer for this question. Thank you for sharing. I wish that others would vote this up.

Answer (score 26):

If you happen to see this error in VS2015, there's a github issue & workaround mentioned here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8518#issuecomment-229506507

This did help me resolve the `property map does not exist on observable` issue.
Besides, make sure you have typescript version above 1.8.2

Comment: Replacing `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\typescriptServices.js ` with [typescriptService](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/Fix8518/lib/typescriptServices.js) worked for VS 15. (*restart vs after replacing file*)

Comment: replacing the above mentioned file worked for me too

Comment: Still no update from microsoft... Why they aren't fixing it?

Answer (score 26):

## THE FINAL ANSWER FOR THOSE WHO USES ANGULAR 6:

Add the below command in your ***.service.ts** file"

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

**********************************************Example**Below**************************************
getPosts(){
this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
.pipe(map(res => res.json()));
}
}
```

I am using 
windows 10;

angular6 with typescript V 2.3.4.0

Comment: Looks like we can no longer just import it in the app.module.ts. Now we need to import it in each service and component

Answer (score 16):

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

&

`npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save`

worked for me

Answer (score 13):

### In Angular 2x

In example.component.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

In example.component.html

```
  Observable.interval(2000).map(valor => 'Async value');
```

### In Angular 5x or Angular 6x:

In example.component.ts

```
import { Observable, interval, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import {switchMap, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

In example.component.html

```
valorAsync = interval(2500).pipe(map(valor => 'Async value'));
```

Comment: why we need to use pipe instead map directly?

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE Sep 29 2016 for Angular 2.0 Final & VS 2015**

The workaround is no longer needed, to fix you just need to [install TypeScript version 2.0.3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593).

Fix taken from the edit on [this github issue comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8518#issuecomment-229506507).

Comment: I have this issue, I also have 2.0.3 installed :/

Comment: i have TS 2.1.6 but still seeing the issue

Comment: At the time of this comment, TS latest is 2.5.2.  This version is breaking for me.  Using 2.3.x works.

Answer (score 10):

As I understand it is because of `rxjs` last update. They have changed some operators and syntax. Thereafter we should import `rx` operators like this

`import { map } from "rxjs/operators";`

instead of this

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

And we need to add pipe around all operators like this

`this.myObservable().pipe(map(data => {}))`

Source is [here](https://medium.com/coding-snippets/rxjs-5-5-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observable-e825129c2068)

Answer (score 9):

As Justin Scofield has suggested in his answer, for Angular 5's latest release and for Angular 6, as on 1st June, 2018, a mere `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` isn't sufficient to remove the TS error:
`[ts] Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.`

It's necessary to run the below command to install the required dependencies:
`npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save` after which the `map` import dependency error gets resolved!

Comment: Looks like more breaking changes which is a worrying

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the similar error. It was solved when I did these three things:

1. Update to the latest rxjs:

   ```
   npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save
   ```
2. Import map and promise:

   ```
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
   ```
3. Added a new import statement:

   ```
   import { Observable, Subject, asapScheduler, pipe, of, from, interval, merge, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
   ```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like latest RxJS requires typescript 1.8 so typescript 1.7 reports the above error.

I solved this issue by upgrading to the latest typescript version.

Comment: If you are using `tsc` from command please check `tsc -v` ;-) Using "scripts" is even better idea, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37034227/478584

Answer (score 6):

Similar error messages will pop up when transitioning from version 5 to 6. Here is an answer for the change to rxjs-6.

Import the individual operators, then use `pipe` instead of chaining.

```
import { map, delay, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators'; 

source.pipe(
  map(x => x + x),
  delay(4000),
  catchError(err => of('error found')),
).subscribe(printResult);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using angular4 the use below import. it should work .

**import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';**

If you are using angular5/6 then use map with pipe and import below one

**import { map } from "rxjs/operators";**

Answer (score 1):

**property 'map' does not exist on type 'observable response ' angular 6**

Solution: 
**Update Angular CLI And Core Version**

```
ng update @angular/cli           //Update Angular CLi 
ng update @angular/core          //Update Angular Core 
npm install --save rxjs-compat   //For Map Call For Post Method
```