# Angular 2 2.0.0-rc.1 Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>' not the same as issue report

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

while this looks like same issue as [Angular 2 beta.17: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947748/angular-2-beta-17-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse)

this is a new version and those solutions don't work for this new released version

I've update to the latest Angular 2 rc1 and can't get things to compile. I had issues with not recognizing 'Promise'  I ended up installing es6-promise typing directly to resolve that issue.  I have tried putting in various import statements but no luck.  I'm running in visual studio 2015

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

return this._http.post(url, null, args).map(extractData).toPromise();
```

but continue to get the property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'

my package file is

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",


"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"zone.js": "^0.6.12",

"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
"breeze-client": "~1.5.6",
"handlebars": "^4.0.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
"typescript": "^1.8.10",
"typings": "^0.8.1",
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
"karma": "^0.13.22",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
"karma-coverage": "^0.5.5",
"remap-istanbul": "^0.6.3",
"karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.0",
"http-server": "^0.9.0"
}
```

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947748/angular-2-beta-17-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse?

Comment: Yeah, that's for a different version and the solution there does not fix the error here.  I'm on the latest version per angular.io packages definitions

Comment: Dan - any luck? I'm here at ng-conf facing the same issue on VS 2015.  Banging my head against the wall.

Comment: No unfortunately, it compiles but you still see all these erroneous error in VS. Doesn't matter what you import, they are still there

Comment: Quick fix: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8518#issuecomment-217960231

Comment: Not working for me.
It works only targeting es6 in tsconfig, not working targeting es5.

Answer (score 70):

did you try with this import? it works for me

```
 import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Comment: it's worth noting that you have to add  import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch for catches as well. (Basically you have to add all the individual functions)

Comment: this was also good to know when using other Observable methods like `publish()`, needed to `import 'rxjs/add/operator/publish';` for that as well

Comment: Problem show up when importing {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'. Instead adding import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'; solves the problem and individual functions need not be imported.

Answer (score 59):

Here is the workaround.  jjokela and VahidN hinted at it also with their comments.
I found it by looking at Deborah Kurata's blog post [here](http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/angular-2-getting-started-with-a-visual-studio-2015-asp-net-4-x-project/). She outlines using Angular2 with ASP.NET 4 project template not the new ASP.NET 5 RC template I'm using.

To fix please refer to these instruction found at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8518#issuecomment-229506507

This fix is targeted to be included with the Typescript 2.0 release for Visual Studio. Until you can perform the manual steps below.

For VS 2015 (Update 3):

Install VS 2015 Update 3
Replace C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\typescriptServices.js with the file in https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/Fix8518-U3/lib/typescriptServices.js. First take a local backup though.

For VS 2015 (Update 2):

Install VS 2015 Update 2
Replace C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\typescriptServices.js with the file in https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/Fix8518/lib/typescriptServices.js. First take a local backup though.

For VS 2013:

Install TypeScript 1.8.5 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48739)
Replace C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\typescriptServices.js with the file in https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/Fix8518-Dev12/lib/typescriptServices.js. First take a local backup though.

Comment: I had a similar issue with the "toPromise" extension of rxjs using "es6" compilation (i'm following the current Angular2 tutorial at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html). This workaround fixed the issue, thanks.

Comment: This worked for me, obviously for Windows only. Had to force shutdown the devenv.exe process for it to take full affect.

Comment: You have mentioned for update 2 and 3. I have VS 2015 update 1 and getting the same issue. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 14):

I was having the same issue. It seems to have resolved after adding this line to the AppComponent class.

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Answer (score 6):

Nothing except

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is most likely related to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7415 which hasn't yet seen a full VS Release. It is possible to build the sources locally and use [VS Dev Mode](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Dev-Mode-in-Visual-Studio).

Comment: "Solving" the problem for me was downgrading to rxjs 5.0.0-beta.2. There seems to be a bug with how Visual Studio handles typings.

Comment: There is indeed a bug, that has been fixed.  There just isn't a released installer yet for it.

Comment: The workaround mentioned in the github discussion (replacing typescriptServices.js file with a new one) fixed the VS2015 Typescript intellisense issues for me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm experiencing the same issue after upgrading to the Angular2 RC. I get VS 2015 Intellisense errors for property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

I use grunt-ts to do my transpiling so it doesn't effect my ability to transpile but it is annoying seeing it in the editor as errors when they were not there before.

I believe the issue is with the Typescript for Visual Studio download.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

It is currently at version 1.8.6 and I believe that it drives the intellisense of Visual Studio and also the build in typescript compilation if that is how you are configuring it. So we might just have to wait for a new version of Typescript for Visual Studio to drop.

Comment: you call tell VS which tool to run by setting external web tools to point  .\node_modules\.bin so you build /run with the version that is defined in your package.config

Comment: But does that control the intellisense also? Or is the typescript intellisense tied in deeper within VS.

Comment: Not sure to be honest but its still nice to make sure you set those tools so you compile to latest version at least ;)

Answer (score 2):

Dan - I had a series of issues trying to get a successful run as soon as I added Observable into my code once I upgraded to Angular 2 rc1 as well.  What fixed it for me was adding

```
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
```

to my tsconfig.json file.  Once I added that line, it rendered correctly both in IIS and using npm start.  My complete tsconfig.json file is as follows:

```
{"compilerOptions": {
"noEmitOnError": true,
"removeComments": false,
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es5",
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"noImplicitAny": true,
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true  },  "exclude": [
"node_modules",
"typings/main",
"typings/main.d.ts"   ]}
```

(sorry about the formatting...it's getting late).  Hope this helps.

Comment: If you don't emit decorators  ang2  will not work but that doesn't fix this issue if your using visual studio and want proper IntelliSense.

Comment: I finally gave up on Visual Studio and will either use VS Code or Atom to write my Angular 2 code...will continue with "regular" VS for all our APIs.  It's a pain to live in 2 IDE worlds but was spending way too much time battling to get simple things working.

Comment: i have the same issue as the poster, and this does not solve the problem. It seems like the reply by David D is the cause

Answer (score 2):

in toPromise.d.ts

add "import {Observable} from '../../Observable';"

```
import { ToPromiseSignature } from '../../operator/toPromise';
import {Observable} from '../../Observable';
declare module '../../Observable' {
    interface Observable<T> {
        toPromise: ToPromiseSignature<T>;
    }
}
```

You can do the same for map.d.ts

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your imports are good. The root cause of problem is described on https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1540

To fix it, you need to upgrade to latest typescript 1.8.

Please note that that when you run `tsc` you are using global typescript (check `tsc -v`) To upgrade global typescript, run `npm i typescript -g`.

If you want to use typescript defined in `package.json`, you need to execute it via `"scripts"`, i.e. add `"build": "tsc"` and execute it with `npm run build`.

Comment: if you look at my package file I'm on version 1.8.10.  I'm using visual studio 2015

Comment: note my vs 2015 external web tools is set to .\node_modules\.bin so I am running the latest TS version

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue. I'm running TypeScript 1.8.11. I have no solution I'm afraid. I think it is a genuine issue with either rxjs or angular 2 rc 1.

I downgraded rxjs to beta 2 and it fixed that issue. Unfortunately angular rc1 depends on beta 6 so doing a full npm install fails.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';    
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

return this._http.post(url, null, args).map(this.extractData)
```

Make Function extractData

Try this one .It will work for you. 
It is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

i got this working for [ag-grid](http://www.ag-grid.com) angular 2's component which is [here](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-ng2/releases/tag/4.1.3).

i needed the typings for Promise which you get with:
`tsd install es6-shim`

then in your typescript options, specify the downloaded typings file like as one of the files to compile in tsconfig.json, ie:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "lib"
  },
  "files": [
    "typings/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts", // the typings file
    "app/boot.ts" // you application
  ]
}
```

Comment: the es6-shim typing doesn't fix the Observable 'map' issue unfortunately which is resulting in 100's of errors in my project

Answer (score 0):

Installing the typings for `es6-shim` resolved the same issue for me:

```
typings i es6-shim --ambient --save-dev
```

It was a [breaking change in beta 6](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-7) and to get round it you could include a reference to the internal typings files inside angular. Unfortunately these have been removed in 2.0.0-rc.0 so you must rely on the external typings for the same thing now.

Comment: I do have the es6-shim typings and things will build but I still get the erroneous errors inside Visual Studio 2015 even though I have imported rxjs/Rx

Answer (score 0):

if you've just upgraded to Angular2 rc1, make sure you're using the new @angular  import statements, rather than the angular2:

```
`import { Component } from 'angular2/core';`
```

becomes,

```
`import { Component } from '@angular/core';`
```

I know it seems simple, but it can cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Find beta release 2.0.0 of TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015.
This release solved same issue on my machine. But remember, it's a beta.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are upgrading from an Angular2 release-candidate ( i.e. 2.0.0-rc.1 ) to a 2.x.x release,** you'll want to:

1. Update your **package.json** to be up-to-date with the file at https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json
2. Update your **systemjs.config.js** file to be up-to-date with the file at https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/systemjs.config.js
3. Change the import statement to:

   `import {Observable} from 'rxjs'`