# ts Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, npm, visual-studio-code

I'm new to angular and npm, but when learning, I got an error, with a code that seems to work on the source I'm trying to reproduce([here](https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview)).

I assume this has to do with my development environment but I can't exactly understand why.

This is my code:

```
return this.http.get('api/cards.json')
 .map((response:Response) => <Card[]>response.json().data)
 .do(data=>console.log(data))
 .catch(this.handleError);
```

On the `.map`, Visual Studio Code give me this error:

> ts Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'

If I ignore this error and go to the browser, I've the same message.

I've created my project with the `angular-cli`, and my angular-version is actually the 2.4.4. The server is running with the `ng serve` tool.

I've made somes searches:

[property map does not exist on observable response in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482202/property-map-does-not-exist-on-observable-response-in-angular) --> I don't use visual studio 2015, also, I'm up to date with my Visual Studio Code(also it seems the bug has ben solved since a while).

[Angular 2 2.0.0-rc.1 Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>' not the same as issue report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030963/angular-2-2-0-0-rc-1-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse)  --> My commandline doesn't know anything about `tsc` and after I've done the `npm i typescript -g`(and restarted both `VS code` and the `ng serve`

Any idea what is going wrong(I suppose something is not up to date, but I don't know what and how to update it).

Comment: You have to reference the `RxJs` library in your module/component/service (whatever it is you are writing here) as `Observable` (the type returned from http.get` is a part of that library. The tutorials on the angular site have a good explanation on how you consume the `Observable<T>` and how to create a reference mapping to the more common methods you want to use like `map` in the RxJs lib.

Comment: @Igor : I think you're correct. Do I've to to do something special to "install" `RxJs`, because just adding `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`to my service doesn't solve the problem

Comment: See my answer below, map is considered an `operator` and in order to load that you have to declare an import dependency. As this is fairly common operator to use (along with others) it is easier to create a common import file and then import that. This is pretty much taken from Angular's help/documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to reference the `RxJs` library in your module/component/service (*whatever it is you are writing here*) as `Observable` (the type returned from `http.get`) is a part of that library. The `RxJs` has many operators that you can use like `map`, `catch`, `do`, etc but in order to use these you must reference the files/modules that they are contained in.

The tutorials on the angular site have a good explanation on how you consume the `Observable<T>` and how to create a reference mapping to the more common methods you want to use like map in the `RxJs` lib. By creating a single file with references to the more commonly used operators and types in the `RxJs` library you only have to then reference that reference file where you want to consume those types which saves on having to re-add all the operators/types in every file across your project where you want to take advantage of them.

Here is an example file (named `rxjs-operators.ts` for this example) with some of the more commonly used methods.

```
// Observable class extensions
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

// Observable operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```

To the top of your file you want to use `.map` (or any other method) add this line.

```
import './rxjs-operators';
```

Comment: Thank you, the lesson I was following was also explaing that. After showing the demo, I was too impatient to test I guess :(

Comment: this is not working for me. i'm importing rxjs/add/operator/map at the first line of my service ts file and still getting property 'map' doesn't exist error