# Angular 2 Http Async await

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await

I need to use `async` / `await` to call `http.get`

I've tried https://labs.encoded.io/2016/12/08/asyncawait-with-angular/

but

```
async getPrice(currency: string): Promise<number> {
  const response = await this.http.get(this.currentPriceUrl).toPromise();
  return response.json().bpi[currency].rate;
}
```

`toPromise()`

gives me  an error :

> [ts] Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

Any solution for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ts Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833875/ts-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse)

Comment: @igor - While that question looks sort of similar, it is a different error. I don't think this is a dupe.

Comment: What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090989/property-topromise-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse)?

Comment: It is a dupe. You are missing the `toPromise` extension method that you need to import from the `RxJs` library. The dupe points on how you can do that in a generic manner (dupe is related to missing operator `map` from RxJs).

Answer (score 6):

Almost a direct copy from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41834083/1260204 edited slightly so it focuses on `toPromise` instead of `map`.

---

The `RxJs` library has many operators that you can use like `toPromise`, `map`, `catch`, `do`, etc but in order to use these you must reference the files/modules that they are contained in.

The tutorials on the angular site have a good explanation on how you consume the `Observable<T>` and how to create a reference mapping to the more common methods you want to use like `toPromise` in the `RxJs` lib. By creating a single file with references to the more commonly used operators and types in the `RxJs` library you only have to then reference that reference file where you want to consume those types which saves on having to re-add all the operators/types in every file across your project where you want to take advantage of them.

Here is an example file (named `rxjs-operators.ts` for this example) with some of the more commonly used methods.

```
// Observable class extensions
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

// Observable operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'; // <=== your missing extension 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```

To the top of your file you want to use `.toPromise` (or any other method) add this line.

```
import './rxjs-operators';
```