# Angular 2 rc.1 and PhpStorm 2016.1.2 unresolved variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, phpstorm, rxjs

After I upgraded Angular 2 in my project to **rc.1**, my IDE, **PHPStorm 2016.1.** can't  find a lot of properties and static functions for example from **Observable** class (rxjs). Like: Observable.of, Observable.forkJoin.

I use typescript as the default language of Angular 2 developement.

I think my problem is similar to this question: [Angular 2 2.0.0-rc.1 Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>' not the same as issue report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030963/angular-2-2-0-0-rc-1-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse), but there is no useful information for PHPStorm.

A picture about the problem:
[the unresolved static function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgOHJ.png)

I import Observable like, this - and this worked wll with Angular 2 beta 16.:

`import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";`

A part of my package.json - if this helps:

`"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"typescript": "~1.9.0-dev.20160526-1.0",
"typings": "^0.8.1",,
"gulp-typescript": "^2.13.4",`

And the auto completion doesn't works :/

Is that an Angular 2 bug? Or an RxJS problem? Is there any workaround to solve that annoying error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular2 support in PHPStorm is not compatible with Angular2 RC.  [WEB-21541](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21541) is fixed, fix will be available in 2016.2

Comment: Bad news :/. Thank you @lena!