# Angular 2: Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services

I'm developing Angular 2 project and following [Http Client Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) for implementing HTTP request But receiving following error when using `RsJx`module.

> Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'Observable'

I have done the following but error still persist:

- Added **`import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'`;** to service module
- Checked the version of `RxJs` library for any dependency.
- imported all modules from `RxJs library`

You can find my source code [here](https://github.com/khanstudio-github/Angular2AppASPNet) on Github. Please guide what should I do and what I'm missing. Thank you.

You can find all the imports in **rxjs-operators.ts** file and I have referenced it in **app.component.ts** file to make it global BUT still I am having error in **dragon.service.ts** file. *Moreover, same error is shown for .map() as well*.

You can find all the version details in **package.json** file.

Additional details are:

- node version: v4.4.7
- npm version: v3.10.5
- angular version: 2.0.0-rc.4
- RxJs version: 5.0.0-beta.6

***Note:*** *For now I have commented the code but you can modify as you like.*

Answer (score 6):

Please check out :
[Angular 2 2.0.0-rc.1 Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>' not the same as issue report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030963/angular-2-2-0-0-rc-1-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse)

"For VS 2015 (Update 3):

Install VS 2015 Update 3 Replace C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\typescriptServices.js with the file in https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/Fix8518-U3/lib/typescriptServices.js. First take a local backup though."

This workaround fixed the "**Property 'toPromise' does not exist** " issue for me.

Comment: Will implement it and let you know. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug in Visual Studio (I'm guessing you're seeing this behavior in VS2015?) I have exactly this issue when I try working with an Angular2 app in VS2015.

As a work around you might try working with your project using Visual Studio Code instead. I opened your referenced repository using VS Code and verified it had intellisense for rxjs extensions (like toPromise) as expected. However, as you sate, in VS2015 rxjs extensions are not being found and show as errors.

Comment: Yes, I'm using VS2015. I have reported this bug at rxjs platform. I will further report this on VS community. Thanks