# some RxJS operators are missing from angular2 CLI project? What to do?

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, strong-typing, rxjs5

I'm in the process of learning RxJS and i constantly try many operators and combinations that i find interesting.

I'm learning form here: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html and [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/observable.md).

I have an Angular2 rc4 CLI project - so i'm using Typescript. RxJS is : 5.0.0-beta.6

**The problem:**

***I found that some operators are not present on the Observable.***

For example: I want to create an observable that returns one by one key value pairs of an object:
You can see how the implementation looks like, as i've taken it [from here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/pairs.md).

```
// Using Standard JavaScript
var obj = {
  foo: 42,
  bar: 56,
  baz: 78
};

var source = Rx.Observable.pairs(obj);

var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('Next: %s', x);
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: %s', err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });

// => Next: ['foo', 42]
// => Next: ['bar', 56]
// => Next: ['baz', 78]
// => Completed
```

But here is what my editor looks like:

[image]

no Intelisense for Observable.pairs()..

[image]

Based on [this post](https://manuel-rauber.com/2016/01/04/where-are-my-observable-operators/) i've aded the 2 imports:

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
import 'rxjs/Rx'; // import all operators and stuff. it's not good practice i know, but only for this example
```

And tryed to install more typings for rxjs than angular cli provides, but is not working:

```
typings install --save --ambient npm:rx/ts/rx.all.d.ts // Unable to resolve "npm:rx/ts/rx.all.d.ts" from "rx"
or
typings install rxjs // Unable to find "rxjs" ("npm") in the registry.
```

And aslo tryed to use:

```
import * as Rx form 'rxjs/Rx'
myObjProperties$ = Rx.Observable.pairs(myObj) // still doesn't work, same error.
```

And aslo, I can't explain why printing the Observable object to the console doesn't work.. I get a `string-function` which is useless. No prototype stuff.

```
console.log('TheAllmightyObservable : ', Observable) // i get:

// TheAllmightyObservable :  function Observable(subscribe) {
        // this._isScalar = false;
        // if (subscribe) {
            // this._subscribe = subscribe;
        // }
    // }
```

I have the **same problem with many other operators**: ofObjectChanges, ofArrayChanges, ofWithSkeduler, pairs - some of them not that important - but it bugs me when i found one RxJs operator that is very useful, and i can't use it in angular2 CLI project.

**Questions:**

1. what angular2 has to do with RxJS ? (i'm missing the general picture i guess..) - is there a separate list of angular2-rxjs operators or RxJS is fully separated package, and can be used like Jquery for example? I mean no wired interference between the 2 - that i can't predict. (digest cycle related maybe?!)
2. where can i find a good list of all the RxJS operators available on angular2 - assuming that exists.
3. is this only a Typescript - typings problem? If so, how to install them in order to have all the operators which are available on the docs? If no typings are available, how to **temporarily** get rid of this `"no property/method found on x"` problem?

Thank you so much for taking the time to read and help me by finding a solution to this:)

Comment: I had the same issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607203/angular-2-property-topromise-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse) and its somewhat similar to it. It's still unanswered yet. I have open an issue on angular github but still no correct solution found. Hope you find solution for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Root issue: You are using one version of RxJS but looking at the documentation for another.

RxJS 5 (beta) used with Angular 2: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs
RxJS 4 (stable): https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS

Those operators do not exist on the new version which is why you can't see them.

To your questions:

1) RxJS doesn't have anything to do with Angular2, you can use RxJS without Angular2. RxJS is just a library for creating event streams, it operate orthogonally to what ever you use to *generate* events.

2) If you are using RxJS 4 then you can use the [docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/tree/master/doc/api) which are pretty good. RxJS 5 is still a work in progress but there are docs that are generated by the build process [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html).

3) It is not a typings issue in this case.