# VS2015 Angular2 intellisense not working

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community and working on an Angular2 application. Recently I updated Typescript to version 2.0.3 and since then IntelliSense and formatting are not working for Typescript nor Angular2. Editor recognizes keywords, but I cannot see Angular2 types, cannot Go To Defenition, etc.

During an update of Typescript, I changed System Environment variable for Typescript from `C:/.../Typescript/1.0` to `C:/.../Typescript/2.0`.

I tried reverting it back, but with no success. Some of the workarounds included re-installing Visual Studio, but I cannot do that.

Does anyone know what could be done to fix the issue?

Comment: I'm having this same problem. There's no referencing, dependency checking or IntelliSense - it only has basic syntax highlighting which I think is the JS syntax. I've tried various methods of reinstalling the tools, deleting the component cache and ran the `devenv` command. At a loss!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment of issue, I had my VS2015 updated to the latest version. I can only assume that this issue developed after a Typescript update.

The only solution I had left is to re-install Visual Studio. Eventually, I did that and I got everything working again.

So the only solution to this, in my eyes, is re-installing Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

For me the simple answer, after spending hours looking around, was to update Visual Studio to the latest version. I found this little push here; https://stackoverflow.com/a/39911281/2345702

I did also reinstall Typescript Tools 2.0.3 just before this so that may or may not have affected this process.