# Solving error - tsc.exe exit code 1

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, tsc, tsconfig

I am following [VISUAL STUDIO 2015 QUICKSTART](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html).
I have done everything as described in the guide and location of external tools is `./node_modules/.bin` and `$(PATH)` 
but at build time I get tcs.exe exit code:
[image]

Comment: This is most likely a problem with your TypeScript integration in Visual Studio.
I would recommend dropping Visual Studio and go for Visual Code which is much more efficient for FrontEnd, but that is up to you.

Don't mess up too much with TypeScript files and VS files, or you will end-up with the same mess I had like I shown in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228507/visual-studio-2015-rc3-typescript-intellisense-not-working-anymore

Comment: @AlexBeugnet I am using VsCode which is the best, but I needed to shift to VS2015 cause I needed the analysis tools for maintainability index and code metrics.
BTW is there any extension or external tool for complexity measures of TypeScript ?

Comment: I don't know about that, you should check out the external extensions in VS or Visual Code, there might be some tools but I have no clue :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in VisualStudio 2015 Update 3 .csproj file-

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />
```

See if this helps.

Comment: as described in the guide : move the $(PATH) entry above the $(DevEnvDir) entries. This tells Visual Studio to use the external tools (such as npm) found in the global path before using its own version of the external tools.

Comment: I have tsc globally installed. Version 2.1.4

Comment: actually I did that too, made no difference

Comment: Try to install TypeScript 2.1.4: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same issue 
after installing the latest version of Typescript for Visual studio 2015 
from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

and clean the solution and run it worked for me.

I am using Visual studio 2015 Update 3.