# VS 2015 intellisense complains about Promise, but builds fine

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Using Typescript 2.0.10 in Visual Studio 2015, I can build my project fine, but when editing a `*.ts` file, Visual Studio complains every time I use `Promise`:

[image: VS Intellisense Error]

Any idea how to convince VS2015 that yes, `Promise` *is* a real thing?

Comment: In your compile options, are you targeting ES6? ES5 doesn't have Promises built in so you will need a PolyFiller.

Comment: I'm targeting ES5 and it builds fine without complaining about `Promise` because TS 2+ has built-in support for promises AFAIK. This is more an issue with VS giving me different compile errors than when I build using tsc/gulp/etc.

Comment: @ Josh M, can you share me the detailed VS2015 version information? Do you mean it works well if you use ES5,  the similar issue has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030963/angular-2-2-0-0-rc-1-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573365/how-to-use-typescript-with-native-es6-promises, it would be related to the es6-promise package .