# Missing TypeScript type definitions for the @Angular packages in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, webpack

Now that I have updated [my application](https://github.com/michaeloryl/angular2-bootstrap4-oauth2-webpack) to Angular2 v2.0.0-rc.1, I am once again seeing TypeScript compile error/warning messages when my application is being bundled in [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/).  The messages come up for any of the `@angular` packages I reference from my TypeScript source files, such as these:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.ts
(1,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.

ERROR in ./src/app/app.ts
(3,76): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common'.

ERROR in ./src/app/app.ts
(4,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.
```

With the earlier beta versions of Angular2, I got around similar message problems with classes like `Promise` and `Map` by including something like this at the top of my `app.ts` file.

```
///<reference path="node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
```

Is there a `d.ts` file for the `@angular` Angular2 packages that I can refer to to fix the problem?  So far it doesn't seem like the `typings` system has anything available:

```
MFO-Mac:angular2-oauth2 mfo$ typings search '@angular'
No results found for search
```

Right now I have my TypeScript `tsconfig.json` file configured to target ES6.  But if I change it to target ES5 instead, I don't get these `@angular` errors, but I instead get errors for common ES6 classes like `Promise`, `Set`, and `Map`.  Here's my file configured for ES6:

```
{
  "version": "1.6.2",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "bootstrap"
  ],
  "files": [],
  "definitions": [
  ]
}
```

I suspect that there are files in `node_modules/@angular` that I could list in the `definitions` section of the `tsconfig.json` file, but I don't currently know enough about how TypeScript typedef files work.

If there is another way to get around this problem, I'd certainly be open to that as well.

Comment: my answer to a similar issue may help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36948893/3532945

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the TypeScript compiler is smart enough to suss out the files definition files itself if you tell it that you are using Node/NPM style modules.

By adding `"moduleResolution": "node",` to my `tsconfig.json` file, the problem messages disappeared and the application continued to work as expected.

Here's my new file (the new addition is the 4th line):

```
{
  "version": "1.6.2",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "bootstrap"
  ],
  "files": [],
  "definitions": []
}
```