# Update npm to @angular 2 is not available

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015, npm, angular

I want to upgrade from angular 2 Beta 15 to **angular 2 RC1.**

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

In my npm package.json inside Visual Studio I do:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "Unavailable",
}
```

but I get unavailable.

Then I did some updates:

```
I updated my nodejs to v6.1.0.
I updated my npm to v3.8.9.
```

It still shows unavailable in Visual Studio 2015.

What can I still try to make it work?

UPDATE

After doing what @David Pine suggested I got this error:

```
====Executing command 'npm install'====


npm WARN package.json ASP.NET@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json ASP.NET@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ASP.NET@0.0.0 No README data
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/core
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/core
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'angular/core' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'ASP.NET'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\\\node\\node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\TGB.2016\TGB.Web
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code E404

====npm command completed with exit code 1====
```

**UPDATE 2**

I also added the correct path to nodejs in my Visual Studio options see:

http://ryanhayes.net/synchronize-node-js-install-version-with-visual-studio-2015/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that **Node.js** is at the top of the external web tools paths in **Visual Studio**, detailed [here](http://ryanhayes.net/synchronize-node-js-install-version-with-visual-studio-2015/).

I have found that **Visual Studio 2015** can be unreliable in terms of integrating with **npm**. Instead of relying on VS to update it for you, open up the `package.json` and manually enter the version you're looking for.

Instead of:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "Unavailable",
}
```

Enter:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
}
```

Comment: Oh... I was wrong... I did not move the nodejs path to the top in my Visual studio options, now it works! at least angular 2 RC1 is installed! Argh... still getting some python errors from the npm execution.

Comment: No because the problem was the missing nodejs entry in visual studio options just like the link I posted. When I moved the nodejs path entry at the top for priority 1 then it worked! I just upvoted you for the general help and time lost ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt (cmd) in your project folder and type 'npm install' or check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076594/asp-net-mvc-angular2-rc1)

The solution in that thread worked to me.

project.json is still not showing @angular module but once you save the project.json it will install all the dependencies by npm.

Follow this post: