# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Subject<{}>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

So, I've seen multiple other posts about similar problems, but none of the solutions have helped.

I am also doing this development in IntelliJ IDEA 15, not Visual Studio. I am currently on Typescript 2.0.3.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Effect, StateUpdates, toPayload } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/dom/webSocket'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { AppState } from '../reducers';
import { NGRXWebSocketService } from '../shared/ngrxWebsocket.service';
import { BASE_URL } from "../shared/ngrxWebsocket.service";

export interface WebsocketMessage {
    data: string
}

@Injectable()
export class WebsocketEffects {

constructor(private updates$:StateUpdates<AppState>,
            private ngrxWebSocketService: NGRXWebSocketService) {
}

@Effect() _recieve$ = this.ngrxWebSocketService.getSubject()
    .map((websocketUpdate: WebsocketMessage) => {
        let message = JSON.parse(websocketUpdate.data);
        return{ type: message.action, payload: message.payload}
    });
}
```

**Edit 1:**

Here is this NGRXWebsocketService.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {$WebSocket, WebSocketConfig} from 'angular2-websocket/angular2-websocket'

export const BASE_URL = 'ws://' + location.hostname + ':9000/socket';

@Injectable()
export class NGRXWebSocketService {
    private socket: $WebSocket;

    constructor() {
        this.socket = new $WebSocket(BASE_URL);
    }

    public sendRequest(request) {
        return this.socket.send(request);
    }

    public reconnect() {
        this.socket = new $WebSocket(BASE_URL);
    }

    public getSubject() {
        return this.socket.getDataStream();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you do `getSubject().asObservable().map`?

Comment: @peeskillet

`error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}>'.`

Comment: @PaulSwetz I said in my question that I am not using Visual Studio.

Comment: Is it just a problem in the IDE? Or are you getting this when you manually compile?

Comment: I can run the application just fine from within the IDE. I only see this issue when I manually compile.

Comment: Hmm... yea I don't know.

Comment: have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947748/angular-2-beta-17-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse?rq=1) ?

Comment: Some questions: What version of RxJS? What do you mean by "manually compile"? Can you include the code for `NGRXWebSocketService`? At the moment, this isn't really a [mcve].

Comment: As @cartant stated, I think we'll need to see your `ngrxWebSocketService` code to solve this. Particularly the `getSubject()` function of that service.

Comment: @A_Singh I have already seen this question and none of the suggestions have helped me.

Comment: @Caleb I added NGRXWebSocketService.

Comment: @cartant I added NGRXWebSocketService.

Comment: @cartant Also, I am using RXJS version 5.0.0-beta.12.

Comment: Does your project use `core-js` or `es6-shim`? Is `typings` in *package.json* `devDependencies`?

Answer (score 5):

This look like a typing issue during manual compilation.

When compiling within IDE, the IDE may have internal typing configuration, which does not exist in your project settings.

1. `npm install typings -g`
2. Check your `package.json` `dependencies`.

   ### es6-shim

   If you have `es6-shim` in `dependencies`, create `typings.json` in your project directory:

   ```
   {
       "globalDependencies": {
           "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim",
           "node": "registry:dt/node"
       }
   }
   ```

   ### core-js

   If you have `core-js` in `dependencies`, create `typings.json` in your project directory:

   ```
   {
       "globalDependencies": {
           "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js",
           "node": "registry:dt/node"
       }
   }
   ```
3. `typings install`
4. Try manual compile.

Answer (score 4):

In the code in your question, you appear to be doing what's required: you've imported the `Subject` and you've imported/added the `map` operator. So it's a bit of a mystery why you are receiving the TypeScript error. However, your recent edit to the question does raise one possibility.

It's apparent that `NGRXWebsocketService` imports an NPM module: `angular2-websocket/angular2-websocket`. And that module has a [`dependency`](https://github.com/afrad/angular2-websocket/blob/master/package.json#L21) on `rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12`. Note that this is a `dependency` and **not** a `peerDependency`.

It's entirely possible that you have two separate `rxjs` modules in your `node_modules` hierarchy: one that's being used in your app (and, therefore in `WebsocketEffects`) and another that's being used in `angular2-websocket/angular2-websocket`. If that is the case, TypeScript will consider the type returned by `getSubject` to differ from the type that you have imported and to which you have added the `map` operator (despite their both being called `Subject`).

You can verify whether or not this is actually the case by adding some temporary code to your `WebsocketEffects` class:

```
temp() {
    let subject: Subject<any> = this.ngrxWebSocketService.getSubject();
}
```

If `angular2-websocket/angular2-websocket` is using a separate `rxjs` install, you should see an error something like this:

```
TS2322: Type 'Subject<any>' is not assignable to type 'Subject<any>'.
```

You can also run the following NPM command to list the `rxjs` installs that are under your `node_modules` directory:

```
npm list rxjs
```

This potential for multiple `rxjs` module installations is something that should be addressed by the `angular2-websocket/angular2-websocket` author. However, if you do have multiple installations, there is something you might be able to do about it (as the `rxjs` versions are identical). If you uninstall and re-install `angular2-websocket/angular2-websocket`, it should use the `rxjs` module that you are using in your app (instead of installing its own).

In fact, all of the dependencies in `angular2-websocket/angular2-websocket` should be peer dependencies and **not** dependencies. I would recommend your raising this as an [issue](https://github.com/afrad/angular2-websocket/issues).

Answer (score 3):

Try to import `map`:

```
import {map} from 'rxjs/operator/map';
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/afrad/angular2-websocket/blob/master/src/angular2-websocket.ts#L97-L99) for `angular2-websocket` it looks like `getDataStream()` returns a subject that emits [`MessageEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent).

Try this:

```
@Effect() _receive$ = this.ngrxWebSocketService.getSubject()
  .map((messageEvent: MessageEvent) => {
      let message = JSON.parse(messageEvent.data);
      return { type: message['action'], payload: message['payload'] };
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

For RXJS v6 you have to use the pipe() with map().

```
 this.ngrxWebSocketService.getSubject().pipe(
    map((websocketUpdate: WebsocketMessage) => {
        let message = JSON.parse(websocketUpdate.data);
        return{ type: message.action, payload: message.payload}
    }) 
 );
```

Hope this fix will help.

Answer (score 0):

`import 'rxjs/Rx';` should fix all problems

Answer (score 0):

i try:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

from here:
https://github.com/webmaxru/pwa-workshop-angular/issues/2
and worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

[https://medium.com/coding-snippets/rxjs-5-5-property-map-does-not-exist](https://medium.com/coding-snippets/rxjs-5-5-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observable-e825129c2068)

This helped me with the current version of angular and rxjs.
Basically you need to use pipe instead of map,  and call the rxjs map function within the pipe