# Return json from web api controller with Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET Core for my backend and Angular for my frontend.
I have an API that gives me my data as JSON from the backend.

I created a service to load the api-data, but it's just returning 'undefined'.

employee.service.ts

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import { Employee } from './employee';

//interface Employee_interface {
//    id: number;
//    name: string;
//}

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {

    constructor(public http: HttpClient, private _httpService: Http) {}

    //apiEmployees: JSON;
    employees: Employee[];
    stuff: Object;

    getEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]> {

        this.http.get('/api/employees').subscribe(data => { console.log(data); }); //I can see an array with my json-data from the api
        this.http.get('/api/employees').subscribe(data => this.stuff = data);
        console.log("LOG: " + this.stuff); //LOG: undefined
        console.log("LOG1 :" + this.http.get('/api/employees').pipe()); //LOG1 :[object Object]

        return this.http.get('/api/employees').pipe();
    }
}
```

What do I have to return?

app.components.ts

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Employee } from './employee';
import { EmployeeService } from './employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    title = 'app';
    employees: Employee[];

    constructor(public http: HttpClient, private _httpService: Http, private employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getEmployees();
    }

    getEmployees(): void {
        this.employeeService.getEmployees()
            .subscribe(employees => this.employees = employees);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting `undefined` in your component? Your console logs in service are behaving correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
return this.http.get('/api/employees').pipe();
```

Into this:

```
return this.http.get('/api/employees')
    .map(response => response.json())
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(
        { message: error.json().message, details: error.json().details }));
```

Here we handle the error (first thing to understand what goes wrong, if it goes wrong) and we are mapping the response parsing it into JSON.

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I use your code I get an compiler-error of the map-funtion: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<object>'

Till now I wasn't able to fix this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947748/angular-2-beta-17-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse). Any idea?

Comment: Did you import the map helper? `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: I did! And Typescript is at the current version.

Comment: If you change the Observable type it will work: `Observable<any[]>`

Comment: No, sadly not. And if I execute 'ng build' I get this error instead: "Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'". Maybe thats interesting for you.

Comment: If so, try removing the `.json()` from the repsonse, and just return the `response` object. See if that works out.

Comment: That makes also no difference.

Comment: Hmmm.. I'm sorry about that. Have tried adding `.json()` to your original code? Like this: `return this.http.get('/api/employees').pipe().json()`.

Comment: Then I get this error: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Observablee<Object>'.

Comment: Change again to `Observable<any>` with this new approach