# Angular Observable: modify data before resolve

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I tried to transform data before resolve by such way, but subscriber gets non-transformed data.

```
@Injectable()
export class OrderService {
    getAll(): Observable< Array<Order> > {
        let url = 'http://fakeapi.com';
        return this.http.get( url )
          .pipe(
            tap( (data: any) => {
                /*
                * MAKE DATA TRANSFORMATIONS HERE
                */
            }),
            catchError( (err: any, caught: Observable<{}>) => {
              console.log('error while GET : ' + url);
              console.warn(err);
              return caught;
            })
          );
    }
}
```

here is a subscriber:

```
this._orderService.getAll().subscribe( data => {
  this.orders = data;
  console.log('\nplanning-overview-page : _orderService.getAll : data ', data);
});
```

Comment: you can use `.map()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

map is the operator for transforming a value in an observable stream, and you have to make sure it returns a value.

```
map(data => {
    // do your transformations
    return data;
});
```

Comment: It works, but there is a note: after I added map() the were arror "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>' ". There is a solution of the error https://stackoverflow.com/a/41014638/7455192

Comment: yea, it needs to be imported like all the other operators, figured you knew since you were using tap already