# Making an array of objects from returned type of http request Promise<Response>

Tags: arrays, angular, http, typescript, angular-promise

I have a service which requests GET request from API server and returns json which i converted to Promise , here's the code for service

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { HttpModule, Http } from "@angular/http";
import { Osoba } from "./osoba";
import "rxjs/add/observable/of";
import { Response } from "@angular/http/src/static_response";

@Injectable()
export class OsobaService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}
  public getOsobe(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:62066/api/values").toPromise();
  }
}
```

Then i imported that service in order to list the data from that promise into unordered list

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Osoba } from "../osoba";
import { OsobaService } from "../osoba.service";
import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";

@Component({
  selector: "app-table-view",
  templateUrl: "./table-view.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./table-view.component.css"]
})
export class TableViewComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private osobaService: OsobaService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    var osobe = this.osobaService.getOsobe();
    console.log(osobe);
  }
}
```

here is the log for osobe

ZoneAwarePromise {**zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
__zone_symbol__state
:
true
__zone_symbol__value
:
Response {_body: "[{"osobaID":1,"ime":"Aleksa    ","prezime":"Jevtic…","prezime":"Stevanovic","jmbg":"2504996854112"}]", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}
__proto**
:
Object

I tried listing objects using ngFor but i didn't get any respond on html page

```
<ul><li *ngFor="let osoba of osobe">
{{osoba.ID}} {{osoba.ime}}
</li>
</ul>
```

How would i create an Array from Promise ? Or at least store data from Promise to list ? 
Sorry for ugly log code i'm not sure how would i format it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal you must your API with .json():

```
import "rxjs/add/observable/map"; //<-- add this import


@Injectable()
export class OsobaService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}
  public getOsobe(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:62066/api/values")
      .map(res => res.json()) //<-- here 
      .toPromise();
  }
}
```

This method return the body of the response.

Check the .ts too, you have a localy variable. It's not accesible from the html:

```
export class TableViewComponent implements OnInit {
  osobe: Promise<any> //<-- add

  constructor(private osobaService: OsobaService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.osobe = this.osobaService.getOsobe(); //<-- update
  }
}
```

Moreover, I think your html code is wrong if you do `var osobe = this.osobaService.getOsobe();`

Because, you assign an observable but in your html you don't use osobe as an observable.

I must add the async pipe too:

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let osoba of osobe | async">{{osoba.osobaID}} {{osoba.ime}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'.

Comment: @АлексаЈевтић can you add import "rxjs/add/observable/map"; into your service file ?

Comment: @АлексаЈевтић https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947748/angular-2-beta-17-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse

Comment: I'm getting different log now , better managed but still i can't list them even after adding async pipe , any thoughts ?

Comment: @АлексаЈевтић osoba.ID doesn't exist in your response maybe it's osoba.osobaID (html file)? Have you got js error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159898/discussion-between-mickaelw-and--).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return this.http.get("http://localhost:62066/api/values").map(res => res.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add then and catch in your service function call like :

```
   this.osobaService.getOsobe().then((response) => {console.log(response);}).catch((error) => {console.log(error); });
```