# Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

This is `app.module.ts` I have tried to done the Import of map in different project and it worked fine, but in this project it's not working.

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { PagesComponent } from './pages/pages.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        PagesComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule

      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {PageService} from './page.service';

@Component({

  selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ["../assets/public/css/adminstyle.css",
            "../assets/public/css/demo.css",
          "../assets/public/css/style.css"
        ,"../assets/public/css/stylesheet.css"],
  providers:[PageService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

**page.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Headers} from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PageService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { 
  console.log('Task Service Initialized');

  }
}
```

Comment: if the project where this probles arises uses angular 6.x, then you should read the changelog for that version and rxjs 6.x

Comment: "Module not found: Error: Package path ./add/operator/map is not exported from package". I am getting this error when i add map from rxjs/operators

Comment: import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

adding this works, Thanks

Answer (score 78, accepted):

There are some pretty heavy change in the use of rxjs 6.

**Imports** :

As already stated, you should now use :

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

(and same for other operators)

I want to mention here the other main changes :

`Observable`, `Subject` and methods that create `Observable`s (like `of`) have now to be imported like that :

```
import { Observable, of, Subject } from 'rxjs';
```

**You will need to use `pipe` to apply most operators**, which might look a bit strange.

e.g. :

```
obs.pipe(
    map(....),
    secondOperator(....),
    thirdOperator()
)
```

instead of

```
obs.map(....)
   .secondOperator(....)
   .thirdOperator()
```

And finally, due to the change with pipe and conflict with JavaScript reserved words, **some operators had to be renamed** :

`do` becomes `tap`

`catch` and `finally` become `catchError` `finalize`

`switch` becomes `switchAll`

other functions were renamed as well :

`fromPromise` becomes `from`

`throw` becomes `throwError`

Comment: Pac0 - thanks for a complete answer, why isnt anyone else bothering to do this! (Ang 7)

Comment: following youtube tutorial things are change 
from 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'). map(res => res.json());

to
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').pipe
    ( map(res => res.json()) )

Answer (score 21):

**In angular 6 `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` become to:**

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Read here:https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

Comment: Seems like its applicable to Angular 4 as well.

Answer (score 13):

The newer versions of Angular does not support map. So you need to install it using the command prompt using the following command. 
First go the the project directory and use the command:

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

Don't forget to import this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Thanks!

Comment: For anyone running "npm install --save rxjs-compat", close the IDE of your project first. 

It took 4-5 min for me to start seeing the output in the console, so take your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it