# i cant import map in my service angular

Tags: angular, typescript

im using angular 6 and i cant import operator map, i try import of tow ways:

using import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'; but visual studio code acused this operator is never used, and i give this error:

[image]

and if i import like this: import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

im give error too

[image]

[image]

how i can import this operator map?

Comment: ``import {map} from 'rxjs/operators'`` is fine . Don't use ``.map()`` on your http calls directly . use ``.pipe(map(yourfunction))``

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 beta.17: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947748/angular-2-beta-17-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import it like :-

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

and use it like:-

```
const example = source.pipe(map(val => val + 10)); Or

getValues(): Observable<Value[]> {   
  return this.http.get<Response<Values>>(this.url).pipe(
    map(reponse => reponse.data.values)
  );
};
```

You are missing .pipe, Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

If you use Angular 6, you use RxJs 6.
For RxJs 6 You need use `map` like this:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

return this.http.post('...')
  .pipe(
    map((...) => {...})
  );
```

read more https://medium.com/@swapnilkls29/rxjs-6-0-migration-37a6f3de0000 or here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md